# ASP.NET MVC 5 LogOff Issue that only works for one session

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, logoff

My `LogOff` action only works for the first session - other sessions from other browsers on same computer can not log out.

Also, the `LogOff` action is not called when the request has been cached by server.

This is my `LogOff` action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    MvcAuthentication.Models.ConfirmList.Remove();
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

What would be preventing other browser session from logging off?

Comment: what is that ConfirmList.Remove() ? have you tried debugging to see where the problem occurs with LogOff action on other sessions?

Answer (score 1):

```
    [OutputCacheAttribute(VaryByParam = "*", Duration = 0, NoStore = true)]              
    public ActionResult Logout()
    {         
        Session.RemoveAll();
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();          
        return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
    }
```

Try this